# why my dp approach is not working for some input?

Tags: c++, dynamic-programming

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
#define MAX 10006
long long int dp[MAX];

long long int a, b, c, d, e, f;
long long int fn(long long int n ) {
    if(dp[n]!=-1) return dp[n];
    else{
    dp[n]= (fn(n-1) + fn(n-2) + fn(n-3) + fn(n-4) + fn(n-5) + fn(n-6))%10000007 ; //Recursive Calls 
    return dp[n];
    }
}
int main() {
    long long int  n, caseno = 0, cases;
    cin>>cases;
    while(cases--){

for(int i=0;i<MAX;i++)
            {
                dp[i]=-1; //Dp table Initiailization 
            }
        cin>>dp[0]>>dp[1]>>dp[2]>>dp[3]>>dp[4]>>dp[5]>>n;
        cout<<"Case "<<++caseno<<": "<<fn(n)%10000007<<endl;

    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Sample Input :**

1 9999  9999 9999 9999 9999 9999 9999

for this input I don’t get any output .Rather it takes all my cpu resource ….. why ?

Comment: `while { ... }` (no condition for the loop) is a syntax error. This won't compile.

Comment: sorry ... while( cases-- ) this is the condition,..

Comment: Also, once you fix that, you are asking for 8 values (for the first iteration of the loop at least) but only providing 7.

Comment: will you elaborate ? i can't get you....sorry - @Kevin

Comment: Your program asks for 8 values: `cases`, `db[0]` through `db[5]` (6 total), and `n`. But in your sample input you only gave 7 numbers.

Comment: With that input, you'll have `cases` = 9999, and no input for `n`. BTW, it would be nice to add the expected output (or at least the purpose of this program) to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the thing:

You are setting all values as `-1` in `dp` array after you have executed the first test case. Try moving the array initialization loop before making a call to the recursive function `fn`.

Ofcourse, as others pointed out, if you have one input case then your input should start with `1` and not `9999`.

Sample Input :

1
9999 9999 9999 9999 9999 9999 9999

```
while(cases--){
        for(int i=0;i<MAX;i++)
        {
            dp[i]=-1; //Dp table Initiailization 
        }
        cin>>dp[0]>>dp[1]>>dp[2]>>dp[3]>>dp[4]>>dp[5]>>n;
        cout<<"Case "<<++caseno<<": "<<fn(n)%10000007<<endl;

    }
```

This certainly gives an output though I'm not sure if it is the expected output.